# Why does updating rails gem also update few non runtime dependency gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I’m trying to update my rails 4.2.11 gem to a new patch 4.2.11.1

When I run `bundle update rails` ( I have changed the rails version to 4.2.11.1 in my Gemfile) there are few other gems that are part of my app that also get updated. 
Referring to [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/4.2.11.1)  I can see that there are ten dependency gems so they get updated which is fine.

The gems that are getting updated to newer version are :

- ***rake*** 12.3.2 (was initially 12.3.1),
- ***concurrent-ruby*** 1.1.5 (was 1.1.3),
- ***mini_portile2*** 2.4.0 (was 2.3.0),
- ***nokogiri*** 1.10.1 (was 1.8.5)
- ***globalid*** 0.4.2 (was 0.4.1) 
  )

**Note**: Few of them are recursive dependensies like **railaities -> rake**, but the version specified in [railties-4.2.11.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/railties/versions/4.2.11.1)  is lower than what I initially had

I want to understand why and how these are getting updated.

current versions : ruby - 2.5.3, rails- 4.2.11, bundler - 1.17.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per bundler's documentation, https://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html#DESCRIPTION, `bundle update` ignores your `Gemfile.lock` and therefore will install the latest version of any dependencies of the gem being updated (while adhering to the updating gem's `.gemspec`).

If you do not want any shared dependencies to get updated, use the `--conservative` option. https://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html#OPTIONS

```
bundle update rails --conservative
```